# Who plans to go back to using Web Applications in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

So, it looks like Microsoft has gone back to pushing Web Application Projects* in ASP.NET 4.0. If you are like me, you converted to Website Projects in 2.0 and have never looked back. I recently spent some time trying to convert a Website Project to Web Application Project and was surprised at how tedious it was. So I am wondering what everyone is planning to do in VS 2010?

If anyone has had experience in going through these conversions, what are some tips and tricks to doing so?

Also, feel free to mention what you use now. Maybe I am the only sucker that converted to using Website Projects in 2.0...

*Excluding MVC since it is the only option there

Comment: I have never used website projects :-)

Comment: Never switched to website projects...

Comment: Wesbsite Projects are teh suck. Web Application Projects FTW!!

Comment: Website Projects are fully supported in 4.0 and VS 2010. Want to clarify why you say they have moved back?

Comment: Just to clarify, both Website Projects and Web Application Projects are supported. I am merely speaking from a perception of what Microsoft is pushing developers to use. I derive this perceptions from all of the samples and starter kits they provide with each release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me too used web site projects and it was a real PITA when I had to convert. Why I had to convert? Because ASP.MVC was out :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're confused. They put web application projects back in Visual Studio 2005 SP1.

Comment: -VS2003 was .NET 1.0 Web Application Projects

-VS2005 was .NET 2.0 with introduction of Website projects (App_Code, etc) but still supporting Web Application Projects

-VS2008 was .NET 3.5 emphasis on Website Projects but still supporting Web Application Projects

-VS2010 is .NET 4.0 emphasizing Web Application Projects and still supporting Website Projects

That is my perception anyway

Comment: @Banzor: the initial release of VS2005 did not support web application projects. Any "emphasis" is a guess on your part.

Comment: Correct, emphasis is a guess on my part. It is just my opinion, but it is derived from all of the samples, demos, starter kits, sessions, webcasts and blogs that Microsoft releases during the promotion of the product.